# Currency field is set to 0.00 when creating record in Dynamics CRM 2011 with SOAP endpoint

Tags: php, soap, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to send an XML SOAP request to my Microsoft Dynamics crm. the record is created, but for some reason my currency fields are set to 0.00 instead of the value I provide. I've used the SOAPlogger with the sdk to make sure the requests are identical and the currency fields are set right when I execute with C#, but when I try issuing the request with PHP the fields are not set right.

Below is the create request being sent.

```
<Create xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <entity xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
        <a:Attributes xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
            <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                <b:key>new_invoiceddate</b:key>
                <b:value xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="c:dateTime">2014-07-31T00:00:00Z</b:value>
            </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                <b:key>new_commissiondate</b:key>
                <b:value xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="c:dateTime">2014-10-01T00:00:00Z</b:value>
            </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                <b:key>new_commissionamount</b:key>
                <b:value i:type="a:Money">
                    <a:value>28.08</a:value>
                </b:value>
            </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                <b:key>new_carrier</b:key>
                <b:value i:type="a:EntityReference">
                    <a:Id>9713bd59-5bca-e211-bd6d-001b21a73d70</a:Id>
                    <a:LogicalName>new_carrier</a:LogicalName>
                    <a:Name i:nil="true"/>
                </b:value>
            </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                <b:key>new_usagebilled</b:key>
                <b:value i:type="a:Money">
                    <a:value>140.40</a:value>
                </b:value>
            </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                <b:key>new_name</b:key>
                <b:value xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="c:string">Action Water Sports - 10/01/2014</b:value>
            </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                <b:key>new_invoicenumber</b:key>
                <b:value xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="c:string">142125103</b:value>
            </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                <b:key>new_commissiontype</b:key>
                <b:value xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" i:type="a:OptionSetValue">
                    <a:Value>100000000</a:Value>
                </b:value>
            </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
        </a:Attributes>
        <a:EntityState i:nil="true"/>
        <a:FormattedValues xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic"/>
        <a:Id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</a:Id>
        <a:LogicalName>new_carriercommission</a:LogicalName>
        <a:RelatedEntities xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic"/>
    </entity>
</Create>
```

Comment: try to pass also the transactioncurrencyid

Comment: I thought that could be it, but saw the currency was being set when created in the audit history. I went ahead and added, but still the same results. Thanks!

Comment: I checked a SOAP library I made and your code relative to money field is correct. Did you test also with another entity? just to be sure no plugins or other things are involved. another difference is that when I do the create I don't add the <a:Id> tag with the empty Guid

Comment: Hmm... I created an Opportunity and Account and tried filling out their Revenue fields, but they too get set to 0.00. The custom entity i'm trying to use doesn't have any plugins on it. I guess I can try to register a pre-validation plugin to see if the value is being passed.

Comment: So I created a plugin that fires when an account is created and pre-validation and the value is that comes in is 0.00. I've also tested updating an entity and it changes it to 0.00. I am on UR16 so I can try to upgrade to UR17 tonight to see if that fixes anything, but I didn't see anything in reference to this on the list of changes.

Comment: So I figured it out! And am embarrassed to say the value node should be capitalized. Once I did that it worked. Thanks for your help!

Comment: which part should be capitalized?

Comment: I had <a:value>140.40</a:value> and it should be <a:Value>140.40</a:Value>

Comment: that's strange, all the SOAP examples around use `value`. Thanks for sharing your solution.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the names of some nodes is all lowercase whereas others are capitalised (one of Microsoft's weird inconsistencies), so it appears the "value" node should be "Value" when nested in another node called "value", e.g.:

```
<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
   <b:key>new_commissionamount</b:key>
   <b:value i:type="a:Money">
      <a:value>28.08</a:value>
   </b:value>
</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
```

Should in fact be:

```
<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
   <b:key>new_commissionamount</b:key>
   <b:value i:type="a:Money">
      <a:Value>28.08</a:Value>
   </b:value>
</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
```

*Notice how "b:value" remains all lowercase in this example.*